# NetworkSecurityConfig does not work on API 31

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add a certificate for my dev version (not needed on prod). So I have created one manifest common for both versions and two version specific manifests for prod and dev. I added certificate as proposed here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config. Which means I added `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">`
into the dev manifest.

network_security_config.xml looks like this (X symbol represents domain):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">XXX.XX</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

It is working smoothly on my real test devices Redmi and Realme with android version 11 and 10. Unfortunately on Google Pixel 4a - Android 12 I receive this exception:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`

I know that Android 12 should be in Beta version right now, but I did not find any changes with NetworkSecurityConfig in documentation so I guess it should work. Am I missing something? Does anyone encounter this problem? Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some break time I have finally discovered the problem. It has nothing to do with NetworkSecurityConfig or API level. I figured out that it is problem with DNS resolving (probably after some update). We have set our own DNS server in company as primary DNS server and Google DNS server as secondary. It is interesting that some Android devices were using the secondary DNS server as the primary one and Apple devices were using our primary DNS server as primary server. So the whole problem was, that the secondary server returned different, wrong IP address than our primary would returned and what I expected.